# Qt5 App crashes instantly unless run with graphics processor

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5

I have a Qt5 which uses QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, and QtMultimedia (for sound only)

At first it compiled and ran fine, however now it crashes instantly. I have found that it runs fine under the following scenarios.

- launched from QtCreator (debug and release)
- launched from explorer  (debug build only)

The weird part is when i try to run the release build from explorer, it crashes instantly at start-up **unless** i run it by right clicking and selecting run with graphics processor. (it doesn't matter which gpu I pick built in intel, or nvidea)

Looking at the debug log from QtCreator I can see that it loads among other dlls these three

```
sLibrary C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\detoured.dll loaded
sLibrary C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll loaded
sLibrary C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrap.dll loaded
```

Is there something that I might have accidentally changed that would result in this behavior? I'm not sure why it would have worked initially, and only started this behavior recently.

EDIT: I went through my git logs until I found the commit which broke it. The only change in the Commit was that I removed CONFIG +=console from my project file.  I don't want to run my program with a console in the background, so I'm still looking for a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Further investigation, I found in the debug log that qminimal.dll was being loaded, and then instantly unloaded.  I found that I needed to move qminimal.dll into a platforms folder in the directory that my program was running from.

I am assuming that not having the console tells the app to use qminimal instead of some other dll. The debug build was unaffected because it apparently always builds with a console.

Obviously it worked from qtcreator because knew it had to load qminimal.